# Getting a variable value from another function that takes a variable

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to get a variable from function that takes a variable. It checks a number on a csv file and if found it shows an alert box. But I want to also show the number shown on the alert box.

If the message box is clicked YES the programs runs, if clicked Cancel it skips that number and continues with the loop

```
def inv_duplicate(inv):
    inv = inv
    return inv

def print_message():
    result = messagebox.askokcancel("Duplicate", 'Invoice' + inv_duplicate(inv) +' has been processed do you want to print again? ', icon = 'warning')

    if result == True:        
        return True
    else:
        return False

inv_duplicate('INV-4546')
```

All I want is how to get the variable in the inv_duplicate function.

I have tried passing the variable to print_message('INV-4546') but I then get the error to print_message() missing 1 required positional argument:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value returned by inv_duplicate(inv) function. You can achieve it by below code:

```
def inv_duplicate(inv):
inv = inv
return inv

def print_message(inv):
result = messagebox.askokcancel("Duplicate", 'Invoice' + inv +' has 
been processed do you want to print again? ', icon = 'warning')

if result == True:        
    return True
else:
    return False

print_message(inv_duplicate('INV-4546'))
```